# configuring virtual host and localhost redirecting to the xampp folder

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I have problem with creating virtual host. I am using Windows 7 x64 Professional. In file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` I have only this lines:

```
127.0.0.1   myhost
127.0.0.1   www.myhost
```

And in file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` I have this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Me/Dropbox/Project/public"
    ServerName myhost
    ServerAlias www.myhost
    <Directory "C:/Users/Me/Dropbox/Project/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course I have restared my Apache server after adding this lines in those files.
Unfortunatly typing `myhost` or `www.myhost` in my browser redirect me to the `myhost/xampp`.

I have already search and I have found on google and also on stackoverflow description how to configure virtual hosts using xampp but how can I recognize I have done everything alright. I know that my problem isn't new but I didn't found working solution for me.

I have also recognized that typing `localhost` in my browser redirect me alsto `localhost/xampp`. I don't know whether these problems are linked in my case.

Comment: Follow below URL which has working solution [Working with localhost and virtualHost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39037872/2363138)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had this same issue.  Your first request is redirecting to the htdocs root directory.  If you look at index.php in the htdocs directory, you can see very brief code that takes the incoming request and redirects it to the xampp directory.

I fixed it by fiddling with the httpd-vhosts.conf file.  In your case, try making the following edits:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> 
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.myhost> 
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\Project\public"
    ServerName www.myhost
    ServerAlias www.myhost
    <Directory "C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\Project\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For my current testing XAMPP (1.8.1) the config file `httpd-vhosts.conf` is located in `XAMPP_INSTALLATION\apache\conf\extra`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and found that I had to go to my Apache24 main httpd.conf file and uncomment around line 501 "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf"
I had never used that before and it was still #'ed out. Hope this helped anyone not finding other answers here. My Apache24 can now see my vhost file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable name-based virtual hosting.

Near the top of the file in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts

uncomment **#NameVirtualHost *:80**

i.e. from:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80
```

To:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

(Note the last line now is uncommented).

Worked like a charm for me.  :)

Comment: I doubt this was the Problem of the OP, because in his 2nd code-block it's the first (uncommented) line! ;-) But nevertheless welcome to SO! :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this

[ file : C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf ]

```
<VirtualHost basic.test:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/basic/public/"
    ServerName basic.test
</VirtualHost>
```

---

[ file : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ]
(open as admin)

```
127.0.0.1  basic.test
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

For me  replacing this one `<VirtualHost *:80>` to this `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` working fine.