# setting up laravel redirects to xampp

Tags: laravel, installation

Hi I'm setting up Lavarel using a book called Laravel Starter by Shawn McCool (Packt Publishing), I've cloned the respiratory via github and have got as far as configuring my hosts file and setting up my virtual hosts. As below:

```
127.0.0.1 laravel.dev

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName laravel.dev
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public
</VirtualHost>
```

However if I visit the link http://laravel.dev I am redirected to the XAMPP page and I should be expecting the laravel splash page.

Any ideas of what I have done wrong? The document root is pointing to the correct direction as it is installed onto my localhost.

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Try putting quotes in the DocumentRoot like: DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public" and replace / with \ and also put ServerAlias www.laravel.dev

Comment: @GladToHelp I tried this but I still get redirected to http://laravel.dev/xampp/

Comment: Is this: 127.0.0.1 laravel.dev   in your hosts file or in httpd-vhosts.conf ?

Comment: @GladToHelp I have put this in the hosts files in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts as per the book that I am reading

Comment: Try the correct answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272531/configuring-virtual-host-and-localhost-redirecting-to-the-xampp-folder and see if it works after restarting

Answer (score 2):

In the new xampp you should use something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAlias laravel.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/laravel.log"
    CustomLog "logs/custom.laravel.log" combined
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

edited with the right serverName. This is my own virtual host file. I also use it for Laravel.

Comment: did you restart xampp afterwards?

Comment: yes I stopped both the sql and apache quit and started the app again

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf and enable virtualhost by removing the #sign in front of  Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

Albeit an old question, I found a solution to this the hard way. Do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName localhost
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This would enable the XAMPP Stack to point to the localhost correctly (I guess?)
And of course don't forget your `drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       laraveltest.dev
```

Your configuration seems fine. Just don't forget to add these two.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName laraveltest.dev
ServerAdmin laraveltestp@localhost.com
DocumentRoot "D:/Workspace/Projects/Playground/laravel-test/public"
#SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory "D:/Workspace/Projects/Playground/laravel-test/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In new Laravel you need to change your Apache Vhost file to stop this redirection from server. For complete guide about how to change vhost file and run your first laravel web app go to following link : <https://answerdone.blogspot.com/2018/01/how-to-solve-laravel-xampp-dashboard.html>

Answer (score 0):

probably, it is because xampp and laravel run on the same port. If so, try changing port before you start running laravel project by this command

`php artisan serve --port=8080`

*8080 can be changed to any other number port you want

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NameVirtualHost enabled?
try uncomment `#NameVirtualHost *:80` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used localhost/appName/public/. This is the only way it worked for me.