# Xampp vhost keeps appending /xampp/

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

Having XAMPP issues here. Im running a dev env locally and a test server. DHCP/DNS/test. exist on the same server and requests with dev. route to my local machine. The PROBLEM: whenever i request a dev.* url it gets routed to my local machine properly but /xampp/ gets appended to the url and i get the xampp default landing page.

```
***vhost example***
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Domains\com.example"
        <Directory "C:\Domains\com.example">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    ServerName dev.example.com ***2 server names so i dont modify when i commit to server
    ServerName test.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyway, not sure exactly where my problem lies... anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So, as usual, i figured it out shortly after posting to the masses :D.

See Here ->[configuring virtual host and localhost redirecting to the xampp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272531/configuring-virtual-host-and-localhost-redirecting-to-the-xampp-folder)

All my requests were hitting "localhost" first so by changing to 
it will always route locally, regardless of what machine its on.

Internet +1 / Me 0